# Is there a way to remesh only a face set?

Tags: remesh, sculpt-mode

Really quick and dirty post. I frequently find myself separating loose mesh from an object just to remesh it for the sake of keeping things smooth.

[image: A model with face sets.]

Rather than separating the loose mesh from the object, remeshing, and rejoining the mesh, is there a way to remesh only the face set/loose geometry my cursor's on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Sculptor Mode mask the region you want to Remesh and Ctrl + i to Invert Mask. Then go to Remesh on top-right of viewport choose Preserver: Paint Mask and click Remesh

Comment: Awesome! Is there any way to make a mask out of a face set?

Comment: For Draw Face Set tool (Shift + Spacebar + 0) press H to isolate Face Sets under mouse cursor then Fill Mask. Also, you can Shift + H to hide Face Sets under mouse cursor and  Alt + H to unhide all.